# SwiftUI Firebase picker not working - can't select items?

Tags: firebase, picker

I've searched around but can't quite get this working. I am trying to create a picker where the picker selection is coming from Firebase (previously added by the user to Firebase).

I can get the picker to display the text/picker items but at different points in tinkering with the code either cannot select any items, or can only select one that it defaults to. After user selects picker they would then add through a button.

```
struct AddPaymentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var paymentModel: PaymentModel    @State private var selectedPlan: Plan? = nil
    var paymentPlanText = "Select a plan"

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

 Section(header: Text(budgetHeader)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(primaryText))) {
                            
                            
                            
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(secondaryColor))
                                Picker(selection: $selectedPlan, label: Text(paymentPlanText)) {
                                    ForEach(paymentModel.plans) { plan in
                                        Text(plan.planName)
                                            .tag(plan)
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 4)
                            .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
}
```